# Reorganizar columnas en DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Teniendo un DataFrame estructurado de la siguiente manera:

```
    pais          A      B        C      D  
0   Albania      5.2    4.7     253.75   4
1   China        7.5    3.4     280.72   3
2   Portugal     4.6    7.5     320.00   6
3   Francia      8.4    3.6     144.00   3
4   Grecia       2.1    10.0    331.00   6
```

Quería conseguir algo así:

```
coste            A            B
pais          C     D     C      D
Albania     2.05    4    1.85    4
China       2.67    3    1.21    3
Portugal    1.44    6    2.34    6
Francia     5.83    3    2.50    3
Grecia      0.63    6    3.02    6
```

Es decir, pasar las columnas A y B como cabeceras sobre C y D, manteniendo D con su valor constante, y calculando en C el porcentaje de peso de la cabecera sobre C. Ejemplo en Albania:

- valor C en A: (5.2/253.75)*100 = 2.05
- valor C en B: (4.7/253.75)*100 = 1.85

¿Es posible hacerlo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `pandas.MultiIndex` junto a algunas operaciones básicas con las columnas. Vamos a partir de un ejemplo reproducible basado en tu ejemplo:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


datos = StringIO("""\
pais          A      B        C      D  
Albania      5.2    4.7     253.75   4
China        7.5    3.4     280.72   3
Portugal     4.6    7.5     320.00   6
Francia      8.4    3.6     144.00   3
Grecia       2.1    10.0    331.00   6
""")

df = pd.read_csv(datos, sep="\s+", engine="python")
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>        pais    A     B       C  D
> 0   Albania  5.2   4.7  253.75  4
> 1     China  7.5   3.4  280.72  3
> 2  Portugal  4.6   7.5  320.00  6
> 3   Francia  8.4   3.6  144.00  3
> 4    Grecia  2.1  10.0  331.00  6
> ```

Ahora vamos a crear un nuevo `DataFrame` usando un `MultiIndex` y a rellenarlo como requieres:

```
columns = [('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D')]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns, names=['coste', ''])
df_out = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=df.pais, columns=index)
df_out["A", "C"] = (df["A"] / df["C"] * 100).to_numpy()
df_out["B", "C"] = (df["B"] / df["C"] * 100).to_numpy()
df_out["A", "D"] = df_out["B", "D"] = df["D"].to_numpy()
```

> ```
> >>> df_out
>
>
> coste            A            B   
>                  C  D         C  D
> pais                              
> Albania   2.049261  4  1.852217  4
> China     2.671701  3  1.211171  3
> Portugal  1.437500  6  2.343750  6
> Francia   5.833333  3  2.500000  3
> Grecia    0.634441  6  3.021148  6
> ```